# JSON.Net serialize single-object array to object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following code

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json)) {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader)) {
                while (jsonReader.Read()) {
                    if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName
                        && (string)jsonReader.Value == rootNode) {
                            jsonReader.Read();
                            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am trying to keep it generic for all objects, as I'm using Json.Net Deserialization.

The problem is, the server returns single objects as arrays, which JSON.Net cannot parse properly to normal objects. Is there any way to force JSON.Net to deserialize single-object arrays to normal objects?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why don't you just check for single item arrays and take out the item at position 0?

Comment: Thank you! I am using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(), and I want to try to keep it as generic as possible, i.e. for all objects encountered as a single-object array I want it to cast to a regular object. Hopefully that makes it more clear!

Comment: But is there a reason why the deserializer has to do that step? Why can't you just check for it and take out the first item *yourself*?

Comment: The problem is it occurs many times in many different objects, as it is from a graph database, meaning it would be very inefficient to manually perform the check as I would have to code a special case for every single class. I'm trying to find a generic way, i.e. through Contract Resolver or custom JsonConverter.

Comment: The solution I guess was to write a tedious custom and generic JsonConverter.